# Did I delete my RDS master user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-backups, rds

We have a MySQL instance running in RDS. A guy that is no longer in the company set that up. As root account, he set `thomas`. After he left, one of the things I did was, using MySQL Workbench, create another root user and then delete the user `thomas`. It's been several months since and I've just noticed that the snapshots created automatically by RDS show `Master Username: thomas`.

It says [here](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/) that

> The master user account is a native database user account which you
>   can use to connect to your DB Instance

From my understanding, that means that it's a normal DB account, the one I deleted when the guy left, and the backups should be failing. But I see no evidence of this, in the Events section it just states "Backup DB instance" and "Finished DB Instance backup".

Can somebody explain what is this master user if not the user I deleted? What's going on with the backups?

Answer (score 1):

When an Amazon RDS instance is created, a **master user** is created with [Master User Account Privileges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html). This account can then be used to administer the database, including creating new users and granting them access rights.

The Amazon RDS service creates **backups** from system logs and block storage. Creation of these backups does not involve usage of the **master** account. Therefore, your backups are not impacted by any modifications made to the master user.

You might want to check that your new user has similar permissions.

One benefit of keeping the master account (rather than deleting it), is that when [Modifying a DB Instance Running the MySQL Database Engine](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.html), you can specify a **new master password** in case the password is lost. Given that you have deleted the `thomas` user, this functionality will no longer work, so make sure you keep your master password safe, or you risk losing access to the database!